# Set up default GNU screen "screens"

Tags: gnu-screen

I would like to set up GNU screen on my headless CentOS box such that when it starts up with some screens already running.

My `.bashrc` file runs screen on the first login with `screen -xRR` and I would like `htop` and various logs to be automatically opened.

Is it also possible to assign titles to the screens at the same time?

Comment: `man screen` option `-S` and `-m`

Comment: Hmm, I can't edit that anymore. Take `-t title` instead of `-S`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start programs in screens by using the `screen` command in your `~/.screenrc` and these commands are accepting options.

Quoting `man 1 screen`:

> Thus, if your ".screenrc" contains the lines
>
> ```
>         # example for .screenrc:
>         screen 1
>         screen -fn -t foobar -L 2 telnet foobar
> ```
>
> screen creates a shell window (in window #1) and a window with a TELNET  connection  to  the machine foobar (with no flow-control using the title "foobar" in window #2) and will write a logfile ("screenlog.2") of the telnet session.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this, in an init.d script:

```
su someUserName -c 'screen -S someSesseionName -dm'
```

Following that, you can use the *stuff* option to launch processes and do various other things to the screen session.

```
export NEWLINE=$(echo -ne '\015')
su someUserName -c "screen -S someSesseionName -p 0 -X stuff 'ls -lash${NEWLINE}'"
```

There may be settings required in */etc/screenrc* to enable multiuser mode for this to work. I've been using this for years to launch perpetual processes that permit ongoing user interaction on headless x86 Linux hosts. It allows post-boot logins to access the sessions by attaching to them as normal users:

```
screen -S someUserName/someSesseionName -x
```